Can Central Limit Theorem make anything normal?
Lately, I am finding myself very (very) confused about the Central Limit Theorem (related to Why is it difficult to take the variance of ratios? and Help using the delta method).
Set 1: As an example, I simulated some data in R (I can share the R code if necessary) and made the following plots to illustrate my confusion (this represents a finite, fixed population we have access to - all other plots will only use data that is coming from these plots):


Plot 1 - Distribution of $X$:

$X$ follows a log-normal distribution with parameters $\mu=3$ and $\sigma=0.5$
The probability density function is:
$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(\ln x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}, x > 0$$

Plot 2 - Distribution of $Y$:

$Y$ follows a beta distribution with parameters $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=5$
The probability density function is:
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)}, 0 \leq y \leq 1$$

Plot 3 - Joint Distribution:
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independently generated:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$

Plot 4 - Distribution of Ratio X/Y:
This shows the empirical distribution of $R = \frac{X}{Y}$ where:
$$R = \frac{X}{Y}, \text{ where } X \sim \text{LogNormal}(3,0.5) \text{ and } Y \sim \text{Beta}(2,5)$$


I chose some irregular distributions and the ratios of these distributions to emphasize non-normality.
Set 2: Now, using the above data, I made the following plots based on resampling:


Plot 5 - Single Sample Distribution:
For a single sample of size $n=50$, showing individual ratios:
$$R_i = \frac{X_i}{Y_i}, \text{ for } i = 1,\ldots,50$$

Plot 6 - Multiple Sample Distribution (50 samples each of size 50) for sum($X$)/sum($Y$):
For each sample $j$, the ratio of sums is:
$$R_{sum,j} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{50} X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{50} Y_i}$$

Plot 7 - Multiple Sample Distribution (50 samples each of size 50) for mean($X$/$Y$):
For each sample $j$, the mean of individual ratios is:
$$R_{mean,j} = \frac{1}{50}\sum_{i=1}^{50} \frac{X_i}{Y_i}$$

Plot 8 - Multiple Sample Distribution (50 samples each of size 50) for Sample Means: i.e. directly from the ratio
Shows the sampling distribution of means where for each sample $j$:
$$\bar{R_j} = \frac{1}{50}\sum_{i=1}^{50} R_i$$


Set 3: From here, I created plots for standard normal variables based on the resampled plots:


Plot 9 (Based on Plot 5) - Z-scores of single sample ratios:
For a single sample of size n=50:
$$Z_{R_i} = \frac{R_i - \bar{R}}{\sigma_R}, \text{ where } R_i = \frac{X_i}{Y_i}, i = 1,\ldots,50$$
Plot 10 (Based on Plot 6) - Z-scores of sum(X)/sum(Y):
For the sampling distribution of ratios of sums:
$$Z_{sum,j} = \frac{R_{sum,j} - \mu_{R_{sum}}}{\sigma_{R_{sum}}}, \text{ where } R_{sum,j} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{50} X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{50} Y_i}$$
Plot 11 (Based on Plot 7) - Z-scores of mean(X/Y):
For the sampling distribution of mean ratios:
$$Z_{mean,j} = \frac{R_{mean,j} - \mu_{R_{mean}}}{\sigma_{R_{mean}}}, \text{ where } R_{mean,j} = \frac{1}{50}\sum_{i=1}^{50} \frac{X_i}{Y_i}$$
Plot 12 (Based on Plot 8) - Z-scores of sample means:
For the sampling distribution of means:
$$Z_{\bar{R},j} = \frac{\bar{R_j} - \mu_{\bar{R}}}{\sigma_{\bar{R}}}, \text{ where } \bar{R_j} = \frac{1}{50}\sum_{i=1}^{50} R_i$$

Set 4: Then, I created plots for standard normal variables based on the original plots:

Plot 13 (Based on Plot 1) - Z-scores of X values:
For the LogNormal(3, 0.5) distribution:
$$Z_X = \frac{X - \mu_X}{\sigma_X}, \text{ where } X \sim \text{LogNormal}(3, 0.5)$$
Plot 14 (Based on Plot 2) - Z-scores of Y values:
For the Beta(2, 5) distribution:
$$Z_Y = \frac{Y - \mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}, \text{ where } Y \sim \text{Beta}(2, 5)$$
Plot 15 (Based on Plot 4) - Z-scores of population ratios:
For the ratio distribution:
$$Z_R = \frac{R - \mu_R}{\sigma_R}, \text{ where } R = \frac{X}{Y}$$


Set 5: Finally, I took plots 1,2,4 and performed bootstrap sampling (where $b = 1,...,1000$ bootstrap samples and $n = 1000$ original observations):


Plot 16: Bootstrap Distribution of X (LogNormal):
$$ \bar{X}^*_b = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X^*_{i,b} \text{ where } X \sim \text{LogNormal}(3, 0.5) $$

Plot 17: Bootstrap Distribution of Y (Beta):
$$ \bar{Y}^*_b = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y^*_{i,b} \text{ where } Y \sim \text{Beta}(2, 5) $$

Plot 18: Bootstrap Distribution of Ratio (X/Y):
$$ \bar{R}^*_b = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n R^*_{i,b} \text{ where } R_i = \frac{X_i}{Y_i} $$


In the end, I am really (really confused). Which of these distributions should be Normal according to CLT?

The Central Limit Theorem is more than 200 years old and can be stated very precisely. No one said that it can "make anything normal."

The "Limit" in CLT needs to be taken very seriously. The limit of the sequence $0.9,0.99,0.999,\ldots$ is an integer but none of the numbers in that sequence is an integer. So the answer to "which of these distributions" is "none".

For sums, the CLT says if $X_1,X_2,\dotsc$ are IIDRVs, not necessarily normal, with finite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and $S_n=X_1+\dotso+X_n$, then $Z_n:=\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sqrt{n} \sigma}$ converges in distribution to a standard normal $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. This means, in this case, that $\mathbb{P}(Z_n \leq x) \to \mathbb{P}(Z\leq x)$ as $n\to\infty$. An analogous statement applies to sample means $\bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n} S_n$. We write this as $Z_n\stackrel{(d)}{\to} Z$.
In practice and in your case, with $X_i$ being replaced with a ratio $X_i/Y_i$, this also means that

$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i/Y_i)\stackrel{(d)}{\approx} \mathcal{N}(n\mu, n\sigma^2)$
$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i/Y_i)\stackrel{(d)}{\approx} \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$

where $\stackrel{(d)}{\approx}$ means "approximately distributed as". Plotting the CDFs of these simulations will show a much better result than the densities since that is what the theorem is about.
For example with $X\sim lognormal(3, 0.5)$ and $Y\sim Beta(2, 5)$ we get the plot for $S_N = R_1+R_2+\dots R_N$, with $N=100000$ and doing this for $n=100$ IID realizations of $S_N$ experiments gives the CDF plots for $Z_N$ and $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, as:

The black jagged line is the empirical CDF and the smooth blue line is the exact $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ CDF.
Does this adequately address your concerns?
